# Limitations with database computed column

Tags: sql-server

We have add a computed column in database. The value of this computed column is derived using two other columns.

For example

```
COMPUTED_COLUMN = COLUMN_1 * COLUMN_2
```

But now we noticed that `COLUMN_1`'s value is incorrect for some existing rows due to which computed column also have incorrect value. Unfortunately we can not update the value of `column_1`.

Now we need to correct the computed column value for existing rows. I search it and found that computed column never updated. Is there some way to fix exiting rows value.. We can not change any existing column value.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Is there any easy way to Select the records where `column1` is incorrect? If you can Select them I would do this....Select incorrect records--update computed column accordingly

Comment: How exactly do you expect to both “fix exiting rows value” and “not change any existing column value”? Can you add a new column? How did you put the original values in if you “can not change” anything?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the table at all? Then create a view that does any modification your require. It can replace the computed column entirely. Make the application reference that view instead of the base table.

Comment: Are you suggesting to change the data during display? Should I keep that column as computed or normal in my original table?

Comment: You said you cannot change the original table, now you can suddenly change it?! What exactly can and can you not change?; Yes, the idea is to change the data in the view. Not sure why you call that "during display" because views are not about displaying data.

Comment: I don't like this approach, because once you add a record to the table, won't you seemingly then have to update the view as well? Seems like too much overhead

Comment: @CSharper what can you do if you can't change the original table? You can't just fix the value there. Computed columns are not updatable either.; You can keep corrected values in a separate table and join to it in the view. No need to change the view definition.

Comment: @usr he said "Unfortunately we can not update the value of column_1." So I read that has he can't update 'column1' but he could update 'computed_column'. Priya, can you clarify?

Comment: @CSharper not sure what you're suggesting. Computed columns are not updatable.

Comment: Computed column value is driven from given formula. In our case Problem is incorrect value in column_1 for existing row. So we want something like we put our value in computed column for existing rows and let the computed column to calculate using the formula for new rows.

Comment: @Priya I already said that this is not possible. The computed column is computed for all rows and, if you didn't make it PERSISTED, not even stored on disk. Use a view so that you can perform arbitrary data corrections. What specifically do you not understand about the view suggestion?

Comment: @usr let me try to explain my problem. My computed column is persisted 

Column_1   Column_2    Computed column 
.099       100   9.9

The Column_1 value is not correct it should be 0.99 but we cannot update it and we want computed column = 99

New rows 
.99       100   99

Please suggest how can I achieve above tow scenarios using view.

Comment: Create a new table that contains fixed values for col1. Make the view left join to that table. Define col1 in the view as `COALESCE(fixedValueFromJoin, valueFromBaseTable)` and define computed column to use the same expression as the value for col1.